# mod_remoteip not showing true ip of the visitor

Tags: apache-httpd, ip, php

I am trying to get the real ip behind cloudflare
I did as I found on google , installed mod_remoteip   then configure it as following :

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.21.244.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.22.200.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 103.31.4.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 104.16.0.0/13
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 104.24.0.0/14
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 108.162.192.0/18
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 131.0.72.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 141.101.64.0/18
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 162.158.0.0/15
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.64.0.0/13
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 173.245.48.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 188.114.96.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 190.93.240.0/20
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 197.234.240.0/22
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 198.41.128.0/17
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2400:cb00::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2606:4700::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2803:f800::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2405:b500::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2405:8100::/32
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2a06:98c0::/29
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 2c0f:f248::/32
```

when I check $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] the ip is not my real ip , and there is not HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR set in the $_SERVER , what to do ?

I added the list of ip's I found on Cloudflare list as RemoteIPTrustedProxy but that doesn't work .